# How to use reflections on python nltk chat answers

Tags: python, nltk

In the [NLTK `chat.utils` module,](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chat.util.html) one of the parameters is "reflections". Other than the definition of the reflection I couldn't find the exact explanation about the parameter. Or I couldn't find an example where the reflection mapping shown on chat response.

Check the below example. If type "go" or "hello" how can get the out put as "gone" or "hey there"?

Simply I want to know how to inject the reflection on the chat pairs answer?

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections

my_dummy_reflections= {
    "go"     : "gone",
    "hello"    : "hey there",
    "my": "your",
    "your": "my"
}

pairs = [
    [
        r"my name is (.*)",
        ["Hello %1, How are you today ?",]
    ],
     [
        r"what is your name ?",
        ["my name is Chatty and I'm a chatbot ?",]
    ],
]

chat = Chat(pairs, my_dummy_reflections)
chat.converse()
```

Comment: Beyond the literal documentation, what do you need? Did you actually read what it says?

Comment: Yes, i read that and try to experiment. But I couldn't use it in practical. In the above example if i say "hello", it doesn't reply "hey there"

Comment: That's not a second-person form of anything so I don't understand why you imagine that should work.

Comment: if i add second-person reflection as "my":"your". How to use it on pairs? Because currently i'm using a pair "what is your name" => "my name is Chatty and I'm a chatbot ". But here I end up mixing your and my in the pairs. How to parameterize it to replace from reflection?

Comment: Did you see the actual answer I posted?

Comment: Got the point. So the parameter "%1" is the one capturing the reflection. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the documentation already (vaguely) tells you, the `reflections` argument is used to map expressions to reflect to the correct person.  Like this:

```
(nltk) tripleee$ python chat.py 
>hello there
None
>my name is my secret
Hello your secret, how are you today?
```

Notice how "my secret" maps to "your secret". That's what the `reflections` take care of. In very brief, the string getting returned to the user has any strings matching the reflections replaced, so for example the first parameter from the user `%1` will have the reflection keywords replaced.

Here is the code for this, very directly adapted from your attempt.

```py
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections

my_reflections= {
    "you": "I",
    "your": "my",
    "you're": "I'm",
    "I": "you",
    "my": "your",
    "I'm": "you're"
}

pairs = [
    [
        r"my name is (.*)",
        ["Hello %1, how are you today?",]
    ],
     [
        r"what is your name?",
        ["My name is Chatty and I'm a chatbot.",]
    ],
]

chat = Chat(pairs, my_reflections)
chat.converse()
```

(I took the liberty to also remove the erroneous spacing before punctuation.)

The task you are asking how to complete would be trivially implemented by adding the input phrases and their responses to the `pairs` list instead.

Comment: Or if you really want to use the `reflections` mechanism to replace fragments in the output before it's transmitted back, try giving it the input `my name is go to the moon with me` and see what you get back with your current code.

Comment: Better if you can mention that "%1" is the one getting the reflection. Thats what I was looking for in this question.